# Ultracart Shipping Method Error

Tags: jquery, ultracart

I am using ultracart api for my cart system and i want to complete a free order for testing purpose if anyone could help regarding Ultracart's this error
"Unknown shipping method specified".
I am using the shipping method USPS: 2-Day 
**Following is the code where shipping method is specified**

### Code

```
 function checkout() {
  var cart = {
    'merchantId': 'DEMO',
    'cartId': '', // will be populated by call

    "customField1": 'blah blah blah',
    "customField2": 'perhaps an affiliate id here?',
    "coupons": [
      {couponCode: '10OFF'}
    ], // here is a coupon for $10 off the order
    "advertisingSource": "Radio",
    "screenBrandingThemeCode": "CSTM", // The demo account has a second them set up using the code CSTM
    "shippingMethod": "USPS: 2-Day",
    "shipToFirstName": "Testy",
    "shipToLastName": "Testerson",
    "shipToTitle": "Sir",
    "shipToCompany": "Ultra Trains",
    "shipToAddress1": "55 Main Street",
    "shipToAddress2": "Suite 101",
    "shipToCity": "Duluth",
    "shipToState": "GA",
    "shipToPostalCode": "30097",
    "shipToCountry": "United States",
    "shipToPhone": "555-555-1212",
    "shipToEveningPhone": "5555553434", // notice the different format?
    "billToDayPhone": "555-555-1212",
    "billToEveningPhone": "5555551212",
    "billToFirstName": "Smith",
    "billToLastName": "Joe",
    "billToTitle": "Chief",
    "billToCompany": "Widgets, INC",
    "billToAddress1": "2000 Montana Dr",
    "billToAddress2": "",
    "billToCity": "Duluth",
    "billToState": "GA",
    "billToPostalCode": "30097",
    "billToCountry": "United States",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "emailConfirm": "test@test.com",
    "paymentMethod": "Credit Card",
    "creditCardType": "VISA",
    "creditCardNumber": "4444333322221111",
    "creditCardExpirationMonth": 12,
    "creditCardExpirationYear": 2028,
    "creditCardVerificationNumber": "123",
    'items': [
      {'itemId': 'PDF', 'quantity': 1},
      {'itemId': 'Baseball', 'quantity': 2},
      {'itemId': 'BONE', 'quantity': 5}
    ]
  };
```

Comment: is it the colon in the text?  "shippingMethod": "USPS: 2-Day", which may be causing grief

Comment: yeah colon is there i dont think so it causing the problem even then i will try without colon